# Why does GameMaker Studio not open from a removable drive?

Tags: game-maker

I downloaded GameMaker Studio 1.4 onto a jump drive so I could use it between two different computers. I downloaded it in a Windows 7 computer, but when I try to use it on a Windows 8 computer, it flashes the updating box, then nothing happens.

I have tried running it in Windows 7 compatibility mode, and I have tried running it as an administrator. Neither works.

Comment: Did you run the installer to install it on the jumpdrive?

Comment: Yes, I installed it to the jump drive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about technical support for a product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programs are not always made to work that way. What you want is a portable version of that software, but such thing has not being created yet either by the developer or someone else.

Programs that run from an installer in windows usually write to more folders than just the install dir. So that if you only copy the install folder to another pc it will have undefined behavior or other issues because the environment is not prepared for it.

You could just install the program on both computers and call it a day, but is has nothing to do with admin privileges or different windowd versions.

Comment: The problem is, whenever I try to use the GameMaker download, it either (1) sits there forever and then times out, (2) sits there forever and then downloads an incomplete installer, or (3) is blocked by my school system. Also, I tried running the install file that is on the jump drive, but Windows 8 doesn't recognize the file type.

Comment: I see... So the other computer is not administered by you. In that case you can try asking in your school if it is possible to allow the installation of that program. That way the administrator can provide her password and allow installation directly on that pc.